# Teradata not connecting using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I am getting the below error while connecting Taradata using sqlalchemy:

Please see the error below.
Please help to resolve it.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (439, "[08001] [Teradata][socket error] (439) WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Comment: That error looks like you are using the old `teradata` package with ODBC driver instead of the current `teradatasql` Python driver / dialect.